# Can we approximate integrable functions by finite-valued upper,lower semicontinuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $X$ and $f\in L^1(\mu)$ be real-valued and $\epsilon>0$.

Then, by Vitali-Caratheodory theorem, there exist upper semicontinuous $u:X\rightarrow [-\infty,\infty)$ and lower semicontinuous $v:X\rightarrow (\infty,\infty]$ satisfying the followings:

> 1.$u$ is bounded above and $v$ is bounded below.
>
> 2.$u\leq f \leq v$ and $\int_X v-u d\mu < \epsilon$

And here is my question. I think it is possible to make $u,v$ to be finite-valued, but I have a trouble proving this. That is, is it always possible to have such $u,v$ whose ranges are $\mathbb{R}$? How do I prove that?

I checked the proof for the Vitali-Caratheodory theorem given in Rudin's RCA and tried to modify a proof to make $u,v$ finite-valued, but it does not work at all. $u,v$ having $-\infty$ or $\infty$ as its value is inevitable in the proof given the text..